# Change Display to none with delay

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script which simply changes the `hidden` attribute. The script works fine but upon changing the `display` to `block` the element shows up at the wrong part of the screen and with a 4 second delay it jumps to the correct position. 
this is the script that i am using :

```
  var form = document.getElementById('it-main');
if(form){
  form.style.display = 'block';
}

var caption = document.getElementById('it-main-start-caption');
if(caption){
  caption.style.display = 'none';
}
```

HTML Codes :

```
<div id="it-main-start-caption" class="it-test-start-caption">
<h5 style="text-align:center;">
some title<i class="icon-left"></i>
</h5>
</div>
<div id="it-main" class="it-main" style="display:none;"></div>
```

CSS Codes :

```
    .it-main {
  direction: ltr;
  font-family: 'Tahoma';
}
div.it-test-start-caption {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 200px;
}
```

These are the screenshots to understand the situation better:

1- Before executing script : [image: link]

2- Right after execution (yellow line shows element in wring place) : [image: link]

3- After 4 seconds : [image: link]

I've tried Chrome, Firefox and Edge and all of them show the same behavior. How can i fix this ?

I am using this on a wordpress website.

Comment: show us code not images

Comment: @לבנימלכה Look at the post again and see the codes after the 3rd line

Comment: I mean html css...

Comment: have you tried using setTimeout? Try using class in css file with display property beasaue css files are already loaded. you can use element.classList.add("classnmae");

Comment: @saurabh Could you please be more specific about setTimeout ? I'm new to css and js. And for some reason changing the class to hidden with css classes doesn't work in Firefox. I've tried that.

Comment: @לבנימלכה Don't know how that helps but I've updated the question with codes

Comment: setTimeout is basically used to run certain code after a period of time, but I guess it won't work here. you can try visibility property of css

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you can try this:
this will visible hidden field in 4 seconds

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hide" style="visibility:hidden">hidden</div>
```

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#hide').css('visibility','visible')
}, 4000);
```

jsfiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/dupinderdhiman/5610k7ad/1/